# How to permanently delete associations in GORM

Tags: go, go-gorm

I want to know how to permanently delete [associations](https://gorm.io/docs/associations.html) in GORM. I tried all examples shown in the documentation but I cannot get associations to become permanently deleted. For example, I am confused by GORM's documentation on [deleting](https://gorm.io/docs/associations.html#Delete-Associations) and [clearing](https://gorm.io/docs/associations.html#Clear-Associations) associations, which explicitly says: `won't delete those objects from DB`. (I don't understand what it means to delete objects without deleting them from the database.)

I have similar structs:

```
type User struct {
    gorm.Model
    City    string `sql:"type:varchar(255);not null"`
    Cards   []Card `gorm:"foreignKey:UserID;constraint:OnDelete:CASCADE"`
}

type Card struct {
    ID      uint   `gorm:"primary_key"`
    UserID  uint   `gorm:"column:user_id"`
}
```

I want to execute the following SQL query in GORM form:

```
DELETE c
FROM cards c
JOIN users u ON c.user_id = u.id
WHERE u.name = `Madrid`
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`gorm.Model` is including a `DeletedAt` field. So on deletion, this will be set to the current date, the record won't be removed from the database, but will not be findable with normal query methods. They call that "soft delete".

In order to delete the record permanently you have to use `Unscoped`, like:

```
db.Unscoped().Delete(&order)
```

Source: https://gorm.io/docs/delete.html

Comment: In my experiments, just deleting with `db.Select(clause.Associations).Delete(&user)` actually hard deletes all associations. I came here looking for a solution to the inverse problem; I would like them to be soft deleted only. Is there a way without going through `db.Model(&user).Association("Cards").Clear()`, which requires listing (aka hard coding) all the associations? Also it should be noted that this answer deletes the parent record, which the question does not want to do.